# Updating multiple charts with a drop down in plotly dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm employing the callback functionality to filter data. I'm intent on filtering a pandas data frame as per the option selected from a drop down. The issue I'm facing is how best to do this for multiple plots. In my previous version, I'm simply plotting without drop downs.

But now, I am unsure as to whether I can simply filter a global data set (pandas data frame) and have the charts automatically update. When I have done this, I have experienced issues in that whilst the callbacks fire and I filter the data, the plots do not update.

Most of the examples I have seen use a callback to directly affect a singular plot. I on the otherhand would rather filter the data frame and be able to update all the plots without needing to explicitly reference them with `Output()` for example. Is there a smart way that I can do this?

Here is a snapshot of the code for simplicity

```
df_result = None

@app.callback(
    Output('fig_plots', 'children'),
    Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_output(value):
    filtered_value = value
    global df_result
    if filtered_value == "A":
        df_result = df_result[df_result["R"] >= 0]
    if filtered_value == "B":
        df_result = df_result[df_result["R"] <= 0]

def draw_graphs(filtered_value):

    fig3d = px.scatter_3d(df_result, x="A Lift", y="B Lift ", z="C Lift", log_x=False, hover_data=['Line'])
app.layout = html.Div(id='fig_plots',
        children=[ 
            html.H1(children='Blah Blah...'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Exploring data.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='jl-3d',
        figure=fig3d
    ),


    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='demo-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'A', 'value': 'A'},
            {'label': 'B', 'value': 'B'},
            {'label': 'All', 'value': 'All'}
        ],
        value='All'
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='jl-scatter',
        figure=fig3d
    ),

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_results() #update df_results
    draw_graphs(filtered_value)
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: ```Most of the examples I have seen use a callback to directly affect a singular plot``` What example did you find that doesn't use a callback to change a plot?

Comment: Because I had multiple plots, I didn't want to explicitly return each and everyone. I am now doing it that way. I was hoping to find a "hack" that could me to refresh all the plots and simply change the filtering on the data.

Comment: As far as I know, if your filtering is executed server-side, dash won't update anything unless it's in a callback. Maybe you can implement your dropdown filtering with [this](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/) somehow?